# vertically align link next to image with CSS

Tags: css, html, layout

**EDIT:**
Yes, this is a duplicate, my mistake (I am new to CSS).  But can anybody explain the rationale behind aligning the image, as opposed to the link / text?  Is there some larger concept at work here that would help me understand the concepts of CSS better and avoid problems like this in the future?

**Original (Duplicate) Part:**
I have a scenario where I want to have a link next to an image on my page, and the link should be aligned so that it is vertically centered with the image.  Of course I don't know the exact height of the image, so this should be done dynamically.

Given this chunk of HTML, how would I achieve such a thing with CSS?

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <img src="myImage"/>
    <a href="#">My Link!</a>
</div>
```

I have a [fiddle at this location](http://jsfiddle.net/nkea4/3/), and you will note that I have placed some size information in the image class.  This is just to simulate an image of unknown size, so please consider the question without it.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I'm new to CSS so I thought there was a difference.  Good to see that the community is living up to its reputation.

Comment: css doesn't really know about images. they're just blocks to display on screen. text block, image block... blocks blocks blocks.

Comment: @MarcB What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Would you like me to give you a long, drawn out explanation, or just point you to the specs that explain how vertical-align works?

Comment: I would like the CSS community to turn off the attitude when I ask a question.  I'm trying to learn, geez.

Comment: No I'm serious. I wasn't trying to be snarky. It's a boring explanation that's not much fun to read or write. I just wanted to know if you wanted me to spell it out for you in an answer or just point you to the relevant tech docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**4.8. Vertical alignment: the 'vertical-align' shorthand baseline alignment property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#vertical-align-prop)
>
> Applies to: inline-level and 'table-cell' elements
>
> This property affects the vertical positioning of the inline boxes generated by an inline-level element inside a line box. The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline-level element, or to a parent block-level element, if that element generates anonymous inline boxes; they have no effect if no such parent exists.

While the elements `a` and `img` are both `inline` by default, the property `vertical-align:middle` should be used on the `img` element instead.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/jJ4L6/)

```
.myDiv img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Of course, because aligning the image is what I wanted to do.  OK, so it works, but why is it like this?

Comment: @A.R. I added some specs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.myDiv img{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkea4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to the image instead of link.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkea4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

just use `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.myDiv img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```